# Grunt Uglify - How to create a source map for debugging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs, source-maps

I'm using grunt in a project and created tasks to minify and concat many .js files.

I'm now trying to figure out how to create a source map out of them with Uglify so the other team can easily analyze the code in the console.

Part of my Gruntfile (in coffee) looks like these two:

```
        uglify:
        options:
            mangle: false
```

/

```
    grunt.registerTask 'devmin', ['clean', 'concurrent:transform', 'useminPrepare', 'concat', 'uglify', 'usemin', 'copy:build', 'server', 'watch:dist'] # Dev - minifies files
```

So, when I run "grunt devmin" on terminal I'll have minified versions but I can't figure out how to create a related sourcemap to them for debugging purposes.

Anyone's got a hint??

Thank you!

Comment: This is part of the the UglifyJS docs which talks about source maps and I'm trying to make it work. Grunt is quite new to me..

Comment: Adding details: If I put "beautify: true" on uglify options I'll serve the files beautified and that is not what I want to do. The idea is to serve them minified and have a sourcemap so the browser can get it on the console to create a beautified version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are various source map properties on the options object that you can set.

You probably want the "sourceMap" property, which is the file name of the source map to output e.g.

```
    uglify:
        options:
            sourceMap: 'mymap.map'
```

sourceMap can also be a function, where the first parameter is the output path of the file that you are minifying.

Comment: As of 3.x sourceMap is a boolean property. Uglify generates a default name, but you can use sourceMapName to set the file name. [More info](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#migrating-from-2x-to-3x)